# Linux GCC Inline ASM Syscall with >5 Parameters

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to create small x86/x64 wrappers around various Linux syscalls to refrain from calling functions inside of libc. The goal is to have self-contained shellcode.

I need to use the mmap/mmap2 syscall, but there are more parameters than I know what to do with. As an example, here is my code for wrapping `open`:

Assume ENV32/ENV64 are set for x86/x64 environments respectively and __SYS_[syscall] is the syscall value in rax/eax.

```
int sc_open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
    int ret;
    asm volatile(
    "" // without this, vim-clang gives me trouble
#ifdef ENV64
    "syscall"
    : "=a"(ret)
    : "0"(__SYS_open), "D"(pathname), "S"(flags), "d"(mode)
    : "cc", "rcx", "r11", "memory"
#else
    "int $0x80"
    : "=a"(ret)
    : "0"(__SYS_open), "b"(pathname), "c"(flags), "d"(mode)
    : "cc", "edi", "esi", "memory"
#endif
    );;
    return ret;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to replicate the `mmap2`/`mmap` syscall using this syntax. However, `ebp` is used as a parameter. Not only does this have strange implications for future use of local variables (offsets from `ebp`), but I'm not even sure how this syntax can used to have more than 5 parameters.

The skeleton would look like this:

```
void *sc_mmap(void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fildes, off_t off)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Compile code using `-fomit-frame-pointer`. Alternatively, save/restore `ebp` yourself.

Comment: Six-argument syscalls are indeed a headache on x86-32.  Read through the macro definitions behind `INLINE_SYSCALL`, in glibc's `sysdep.h` ([x86-32](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h;h=449b23e49bef5aaea01e969363ca00698a7ea1fe;hb=HEAD#l123); [x86-64](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h;h=7b8bd795b7cf0e964ae44284123d9852f198354a;hb=HEAD#l140)) _very carefully_.  If you still don't know what to do, ask a new question about exactly what you're still stuck on.

Comment: You may find that you have a better time writing raw assembly language rather than attempting to use inline assembly.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing. I simply wrote it in assembly, assembled with nasm, and linked it with gcc.